# ag-Grid : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentFromFramework' of null

Tags: select, combobox, dropdown, ag-grid, angular8

I am trying to implement combobox select with "agRichSelectCellEditor" in Anuglar 8 and getting following error in console while trying to edit the field.

For reference: I am following https://plnkr.co/edit/PgRoxXgx7NL5epn2B1X9?p=preview this is an example.

```
{
    headerName: "Prefix Code",
    field: "prefixCode",
    filter: true,
    editable: true,
    cellRenderer: "prefixCodeRenderer",
    cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
    cellEditorParams: {
      values: [1, 2, 3],
      cellRenderer: "prefixCodeRenderer"
    }
}
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentFromFramework' of null

Answer (score 6):

You probably have forgot to define the Framework components like the example

```
this.frameworkComponents = {
  moodRenderer: MoodRenderer,
  moodEditor: MoodEditor,
  numericEditor: NumericEditor
};
```

Or if you did, please link a project with the code that is not working.

Comment: **@Ghanima**
I have already used it :
```this.frameworkComponents = {
      prefixCodeRenderer: PrefixCodeRenderer,
 }```

For the time beingm I am using ```cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor"``` to overcome my requirement .

Comment: Then please provide the core you're using in a plnkr